# iPhone 6 Plus Doesn't Recognize filter: blur() Css

Tags: ios, iphone, css, filter

Okay, so I was styling a blurred header for my company and one of our QA ran into a strange issue. Basically illustrated below.

HTML:

```
    <!-- HTML FILE -->
    <div class="bg-item"></div>
```

CSS:

```
/* Stylesheet */
.bg-item { 
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    display: block;
    filter: blur(40px);
    background: url('../img/bg.jpg') 0 0 / cover no-repeat;
}
```

It works on all devices and browsers, except when I set Safari to be in 3x iPhone 6 Plus size (hehe) - then the css style shows that it is invalid...

Verified it on an actual iPhone 6 Plus as well and this holds true? Is it an Apple bug or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Are you using the `-webkit-` prefix? According to [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-filters), it's required in iOS.

Comment: Yeah either way it doesn't work, I use auto-prefixer btw on gulp process for the dist version I'm testing on, I just left it like this for simplicity sake.

Comment: Yep, I'm seeing the same thing on desktop Safari version 9.0 (11601.1.56) when in Responsive Design Mode… toggling out of 3x mode fixes the blur… very weird bug!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it IS a bug on Apple's end, at least it would appear that way considering they didn't openly declare they've dropped support for CSS Filters.

You can use their new backdrop filter to work around this though pretty easily, I've demo'd it below.

HTML:

```
    <!-- HTML FILE -->
    <div class="img-wrap">
        <div class="bg-overlay"></div>
        <div class="bg-item"></div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
/* Stylesheet */
.img-wrap { 
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    display: block;
}
.bg-overlay {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.bg-img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    filter: blur(60px);
    background: url('../img/bg.jpg') 0 0 / cover no-repeat;
}

//Only show on 3x density devices
@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3) {
    .ios.bg-overlay {
        -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(60px); //Blurs bg behind it
    }
}
```

In a nutshell, just set up a media query to only use the backdrop on 3x ratio devices on webkit - and as much as I hate to say it android chrome will NOT know what to do with this so you will want to make sure this only gets applied to SAFARI, IOS devices - and it should take care of it.

Hope that helps!